# Organizing Files in PHPDocumentator

Tags: phpdoc

I have recently installed PHPDocumentator 2 and like it so far. One thing I would like to do is organize the files in a more meaningful way (specifically by using the actual folder structure) and in alphabetical order.

Here is a screenshot of my classes as it stand now:

[image]

Note that they are not in alphabetical order at all. The actual folder structure is like so:

```
system/
  - Database
  - all Form classes
  - Tester
extra/
  - Registration
  - ConfigForm
```

I'm not using namespaces, but I have @package's on all of the classes.

Can I fix this in phpdoc.dist.xml or do I need to create a new template?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: Here is a sample docBlock:

```
/**
  * FormElement Class
  *
  * @category System
  * @package  Form
  */
abstract class FormElement
{
```

Comment: In case you're still interested, you can follow along on the progress of this feature request at [this github bug report](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/template.clean/issues/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sampling the various output templates available with phpDocumentor 2.1.0, I see that some do alphabetize that left-side listing, while others do not.  It is possible, even likely, that those that do not alphabetize the list are bugs in those templates.

Regarding your organizing via @package, your expectations are correct.  However, I see in your image that you are showing the "\" global namespace listing rather than the Packages listing.  You'll want to choose a template based on how it presents the Packages view.  I'd suggest trying the Abstract template first and see if it fits your liking.  I see that it alphabetizes its listing of Packages, as well as its list of Classes in a Package.

Comment: Abstract does more of what I want for sure. I wish the phpdoc documentation was better! Seems to me it should be. Is there a good guide out there for creating a template with phpdoc?

Comment: The barebones guide is here (http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-template-builders/getting-started/quick-start.html).  A more detailed guide is planned later on.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry for my bad english

I had the same problem (with PHPDocumentator 2 too)!

[The solution of @ashnaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19731111) of using `@package` in the class's comment, as they say in [the documentation of PHPDocumentator](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/package.html#), WAS **NOT working in the left menu**, but did show the package in the right menu!

After hours of searching, I find out how to group my classes in the left menu!

In all the files I want in my documentation, I add a **namespace**. In my case, namespace's name is the folder/directory my classes were into. But you can group the classes with the names you want! So here the solution :

- **Add a namespace in all the classes you want to group together**

  - To **group classes together**, they need to have the **same namespace**
  - You can have multiple namespaces!
- The namespace line must be the **FIRST LINE OF CODE IN THE PAGE** !! So directly **under the `<?php` line** ! The beginning of the class should look like this :

  ```
  <?php 
  namespace GroupName;
  ```

  and run your phpdoc command (I use `phpdoc -m --validate --force`) and you should have the left menu with the structure.